# jq and bash: object construction with --arg is not working

Tags: bash, jq

Given the following input:

```
J='{"a":1,"b":10,"c":100}  
{"a":2,"b":20,"c":200}  
{"a":3,"b":30,"c":300}'
```

The command

```
SELECT='a,b'; echo $J | jq -c -s --arg P1 $SELECT '.[]|{a,b}'
```

produces

```
{"a":1,"b":10}  
{"a":2,"b":20}  
{"a":3,"b":30}
```

but this command produces unexpected results:

```
SELECT='a,b'; echo $J | jq -c -s --arg P1 $SELECT '.[]|{$P1}'  
{"P1":"a,b"}
{"P1":"a,b"}
{"P1":"a,b"}
```

How does one get jq to treat an arg string literally?

Using tostring gives an error

```
SELECT='a,b'; echo $J | jq -c -s --arg P1 $SELECT '.[]|{$P1|tostring}'  
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting
issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:  
.[]|{$SELECT|tostring}           
jq: 1 compile error
```

SELECT needs to be a variable and not hardcoded in the script.

Comment: Huh? "Literally" isn't what you're asking for. You're asking it for to be parsed as code (into two separate tokens), not treated as a literal.

Comment: Treating `a,b` as a literal means treating it as a single three-character string, which is **exactly** what `jq` is doing already.

Comment: ...which is to say: The current behavior is far more correct than the behavior you're asking for; if data were treated as code, `jq` couldn't ever be used in a situation where its input were untrusted.

Comment: BTW, re: variable naming convention -- see the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html indicating that all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use (and that an application can use any lowercase name without risk of interfering with OS tool operation).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: SELECT is a bash variable defined elsewhere, not an untrusted input.  It is used correctly for my purposes.

Comment: Without knowing how a variable is defined, considering it untrusted is a priori the safe thing -- worst data loss incident I've seen was caused by a filename being handled in an untrustworthy way (and that name wasn't even intentionally malicious, just generated by code using a buggy library with a buffer overflow that corrupted the filename).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SELECT needs to be a variable and not hardcoded in the script.

Assuming you want to avoid the risks of "code injection" and that you want the shell variable SELECT to be a simple string such as "a,b", then consider this reduce-free solution along the lines you were attempting:

```
J='{"a":1,"b":10,"c":100}'
SELECT='a,b'
echo "$J" |
  jq -c --arg P1 "$SELECT" '
    . as $in | $P1 | split(",") | map( {(.): $in[.]} ) | add'
```

Output:

```
{"a":1,"b":10}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### If you really want your data to be parsed as syntax...

This is not an appropriate use case for `--arg`. Instead, substitute into the code:

```
select='a,b'; jq -c -s '.[]|{'"$select"'}' <<<"$j"
```

Note that this has all the usual caveats of code injection: If the input is uncontrolled, the output (or other behavior of the script, particularly if `jq` gains more capable I/O features in the future) should be considered likewise.

---

#### If you want to split the literal string into a list of keys...

Here, we take your `select_str` (of the form `a,b`), and generate a map: `{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}`; then, we can break each data item into entries, select only the items in the map, and there's our output.

```
jq --arg select_str "$select" '
($select_str
 | split(",")
 | reduce .[] as $item ({}; .[$item]=$item)) as $select_map
 | with_entries(select($select_map[.key]))' <<<"$j"
```

Comment: This is good option too, but the selected answer is more concise.